# Registration Form Amendment

Tags: joomla-3.4

I have the a registration form on my joomla site that users complete to register. Unfortunately, I can't see to find the link / pluggin / module to make changes to the form.

Is someone familiar with form? If so, can they point to me where I can make the change.

my site is www.keylooplabs.com

Cheers

Carlton[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user registration form is part of Joomla, and you can change the settings in the following places from your Admin area:

- **Users** -> **Manage** -> **Options button** (upper right corner)
  This will allow you to change how the registration process works.
- **Extensions** -> **Plugins** -> **User Profile plugin**
  Here you can change what fields are displayed, and if they are required or not.

[image]

If you want to make more changes, you need to create a template override by copying the file `ROOT/components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php` to `ROOT/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/com_users/default.php`

Comment: that the User Profile plugin worked. Cheers mate.